# Firefox debugger server changes my search bar coloring

Tags: visual-studio-code, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm using VSCode debugging plugin for Firefox in order to debug my angular web apps.
The plugin states that it only works when launching Firefox with "-start-debugger-server" argument.
This launches Firefox with an interface warning, recoloring search bar bright striped-red:

[image: search bar]

Is there any way to disable this recoloring and turn it back to normal color? I understand the security intent, but I really don't need it.